# Which wordpress action fires after crunching

Tags: uploads

Which wordpress action fires immediately after wordpress finished crunching audio files.

I know about **add_attachment** but it fires Immediately the the audio is uploadeded.

**Edit**
I have a plugin that converts uploaded audio files to post using the add_attachment action, so I want to automatically use the featured image of the last audio uploaded as the featured image of the post it is converted to. I used the wordpress get_post, publish_post action and set_post_thumbnail. When I publish a new post every thing works fine but when I uploaded an audio and it is converted to wordpress posts the featured image doesn't work.

Comment: when you say crunching, what do you mean? Standard WordPress might read header tags to fill in attachment post meta, but it does not process the audio file in any way. What were you trying to implement when you encountered the problem?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, I have a plugin that converts uploaded audio files to post, so I want to automatically use the featured image of the last audio uploaded as the featured image of the post it is converted to. I used the wordpress get_post, publish_post action and set_post_thumbnail. When I publish a new post every thing works fine but when I uploaded an audio and it is converted to wordpress posts the featured image doesn't work

Comment: Is this a plugin you wrote yourself or a 3rd party plugin? If you wrote it yourself we're going to need to see code. If it's a 3rd party plugin you'll need to ask at their support route as 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here and not in this sites scope.

Comment: Yes I wrote the plugin my self

Comment: ok, you'll need to edit your question so that it includes the code to debug, we can't help you if we don't know what you're working with. I'm assuming you have code to extract the image from the audio file that you've tested with test data to confirm works, and you have code that creates a post when an audio file is added to the media library? As well as code that attempted to set the featured image but failed? If so, edit your question to include them in code blocks so they can be debugged